# UV stretching after unwrapping (on curved mashes) (closed)

Tags: modeling, uv

I had made a tube with the spin tool and after unwrapping it with "mark seam" uv editor gave that picture [image]

I had tried to alige faces but it had no result.

Face orientation is correct, and have no extra geometry i did merge by distance.
I just have no clues what is going wrong

Blender  v.4.01

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong here, that’s just how UV unwrapping works. Think about it. If you had to make a flat surface wrap around this pipe that changes diameter, what would that wrapping be shaped like? The UV on wrapper will do its best to keep all faces as undistorted as possible, so you end up with this warped shape, instead of what would be a wrapper that somehow squashes that diameter change into 2D space, leaving it heavily distorted.

You can try setting up UV seams in various locations to make it unwrap to a flat surface better, such as at the corners of diameter change so you end up with two can wrappers and a ring. Or, you can use the UV squares add-on to change the UVs after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, at least i know that curved mashes need to hide from view